# Android OpenCV Object Detection

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

Im trying to implement something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjxWpKCQqJc on android.

Here my code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat novo = new Mat();
    Mat resp = new Mat();
    Mat homer = new Mat();

    //resp = inputFrame.gray();
    novo = inputFrame.gray();

    Mat lido = new Mat();
    try {
        lido = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.homer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Imgproc.cvtColor(lido, homer, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    FeatureDetector surf = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);

    MatOfKeyPoint keypointsHomer = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    surf.detect(homer, keypointsHomer);
    surf.detect(novo, keypoints);

    DescriptorExtractor SurfExtractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);

    Mat descriptors = new Mat();
    Mat homerDescriptors = new Mat();

    SurfExtractor.compute(novo, keypoints, descriptors);
    SurfExtractor.compute(homer, keypointsHomer, homerDescriptors);

    DescriptorMatcher m = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

    m.match(descriptors, homerDescriptors, matches);

    Features2d.drawMatches(novo, keypoints, homer, keypointsHomer, matches, resp);

    return resp;
}
```

And i got the following error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2345114/error_android.png

If i try draw the keypoints like this:

```
Features2d.drawKeypoints(novo, keypoints, resp);
Features2d.drawKeypoints(homer, keypointsHomer, resp);
```

Both works fine!
Whats i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm finally finish that! Heres a link with the final result. [Simpson Detector (OpenCV)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.raphael.detector&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiYnIucmFwaGFlbC5kZXRlY3RvciJd) I hope this helps you in some way, on Google Play you can see more details about that project and download the source code. Feel free to send me a e-mail.

Comment: I rounded the problem in another way.
I guess Features2d.drawMatches not work on android. Probably only works with JVM and with Components that does not exist in android. If anyone can confirm I am grateful.

Google removed the app and did not say why! = (
 
But the source code is available together with the apk on my site quintao.info Result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2KHje-Pf10

Source: https://github.com/raphaelquintao/SimpsonDetector